# JavaMail and the Blackberry JRE

Tags: blackberry, java-me, gmail, jakarta-mail

I am trying to make use of the JavaMail jar on my blackberry app so I can access my GMail emails. I usually make use of this sort of function:

```
Properties props = System.getProperties();
props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");

String html_email = ""; 

    try {
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
        Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
        store.connect("imap.gmail.com", email, password);
```

However, eclipse is complaining about the `Properties` object as I am not making use of the standard JRE but rather the blackberry JRE.

Is there anyway, I can work around this with minimal changes to my function as far as the `Properties` is concerned?

In addition, I am having trouble with the use of `System`:

> The method getProperties() is
>   undefined for the type System.

Is this even likely to work?!

Thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, looks like [JavaMail is not built for use on JavaME](https://java.net/projects/javamail/forums/forum/topics/81586-JavaMail-works-on-J2ME).